# related tables in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two related tables in mongodb.
such as users and students.
Since each student is also a user, I store the userid as a userid in the students table. Should I do this? What is the best practice in this regard?
I'm a little confused as I'm coming from a relational database.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPKk3.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjftL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will follow that pattern, will be better if you save the userId in the students collection (not a table) as ObjectId instead of string, because that will allow you to do lookups easily.

Another idea can be save the `type` attribute in users collection to specify what kind of user a user is. Because as I see your are using exactly the same information in both collections, the only thing that will be different is the context.